# POCO library hanging on android when using ssl

Tags: android, ssl, android-ndk, poco

I built openssl and POCO library for android. In my app I am trying to use SSL. The problem is when I create the handler, it hangs and never returns. It happens regardless of which type of certificate handler I use. What could be going wrong here?

My code:

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
// Creating this handler is where it hangs.
SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> pCert = new AcceptCertificateHandler(false);
//It never gets to this line.
Context::Ptr pContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, true, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
```

Comment: There's an Android/OpenSSL minefield due to Zygote loading Android's supplied OpenSSL. What version of OpenSSL are you compiling/linking against? Your process inherits from Zygote, and Zygote's version is 0.9.8. So if you compile against 1.0.1, then you get all kinds of bizarre errors. See [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: fwiw I'm running fine with 1.0.1e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this to work by building POCO using Android make files (.mk) instead of using the standalone toolchain like I was. I don't know what the difference was but it works properly now.

Answer (score 4):

Oh wow someone else on SO doing POCO/SSL on Android.  Welcome to hell :P

Anyway, it's confusing that you would have it hang there - I assume you've validated with prints?  Perhaps your calling thread is being killed off from the Android side?  Obviously you shouldn't be calling this from the UI thread so there's that.

If none of that is at issue then I'm not sure what the problem is.  My init SSL is pretty much exactly yours:

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> accept_cert_handler =
    new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(false);
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> console_handler =
    new Poco::Net::KeyConsoleHandler(false);
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context =
    new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "",
    Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, true,
    "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");     

Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().
    certificateHandlerFactoryMgr().
    setFactory("accept_handler",
    new Poco::Net::CertificateHandlerFactoryImpl<AcceptCertificateHandler>());

Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(console_handler, 
                                                   accept_handler,
                                                   context);
```

Comment: I'm not calling from the UI thread, but in an ASyncTask.  Hell indeed.

Comment: assuming you can get this bit working - depending on what you're trying to do I may be able to provide you with some useful advice about the NDK/jni/poco stack if you need some.  Just PM me anytime